# I have two LoaderManager(LM) in one activity, and i'll like to use the data in onLoadfinished() of the 1st LM in the onCreateLoader() of the 2nd LM

Tags: java, android

I apologize if my code doesn't look okay enough and if what i want to implement is not possible because i am new to android programming:

My First LoaderManager and the data i want to use is mCryptoString and mFiatString from the onLoadFinished() method:

```
private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> cursorLoader
        = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        if (data == null || data.getCount() < 1) {
            return;
        }

        if (data.moveToFirst()) {

            int fiatColumnIndex = data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CurrencyEntry.COLUMN_FIATCURRENCY_NAME);
            int cryptoColumnIndex = data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CurrencyEntry.COLUMN_CRYPTOCURRENCY_NAME);

            String fiatValue = data.getString(fiatColumnIndex);
            String cryptoValue = data.getString(cryptoColumnIndex);

            mCryptoString = fiatValue;
            mFiatString = cryptoValue;

            mFiatTextView.setText(fiatValue);
            mCryptoTextView.setText(cryptoValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        ...
    }
};
```

My Second LoaderManager where i want to use the mCryptoString and mFiatString in the onCreateLoader() method:

```
private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String> myJsonResponseLoader
        = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String>() {
    @Override
    public Loader<String> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        String CONVERSION_URL = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=" + mCryptoString + "&tsyms=" + mFiatString;
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "two values in json: " + mCryptoString + mFiatString);


        return new ConversionLoader(ConversionActivity.this, CONVERSION_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String> loader, String data) {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<String> loader) {
       ...
    }
};
```

I don't know how this can be done, any help will mostly be appreciated.